# Jquery each function and click event not working

Tags: jquery

I want to remove each selected element with same class element. My jquery coding is given bellow

```
$(".del_layer").each(function(){        $(this).click(function(){
           $(this).parent().remove();
                });

            });
```

my html structure is

```
<li class="select_layerList" data-refind="0">
<img width="20px" src="tmp_card_imgs/a.png">
Layer 0:Image
<span class="del_layer" style="cursor:pointer;">X</span>
</li>
<li class="select_layerList" data-refind="0">
<img width="20px" src="tmp_card_imgs/b.png">
Layer 0:Image
<span class="del_layer" style="cursor:pointer;">X</span>
</li>
```

But each function is not working.
How can I solve this

Comment: You don't need to keep your `.click()` inside the `.each()`.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hcB4T/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/4LeuA/

Ensure you have the `DOM` has loaded, place your code inside a `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove each function because you can select them via class name and put your script on document ready like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.del_layer').on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this

```
 $(".del_layer").on('tap',function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to traverse through `.each()`, just apply the event to the selector and remove its parent:

```
$(".del_layer").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

and you can use `.closest()` function to traverse up to the desired parent.

```
$(".del_layer").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using event delegation, you can set the same handler once:

```
$(document).on('click', '.del_layer', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```